# Swift project in Xcode: Three different apps within same project

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have two apps as an individual project written in Swift in Xcode: `process1.app` and `process2.app`. Also i have "installer" for those two apps named `main.app` which has GUI implemented.

I am not able to connect those three apps within same project, where and when user installs `main.app`, he is going to install `process1.app` and `process2.app`.

Can you give me some ideas how to connect all them within same project?

Comment: Just create a Workspace where you can see all 3? You obviously can't "connect" them, as they're 3 different processes, but they can share a static/dynamic library if you want to share code.

Comment: You can also make them belong to the same app group so they can share persistent data as well.

Comment: But, when I make final executable version, how to include all three apps in one?

Comment: @viktor.radovic You can't put different apps in the same bundle, so that all apps are installed at the same time. Do you need the apps in your company or will they be available in the AppStore?

Comment: Why is this tagged both [tag:ios] and [tag:osx]?  It sounds like you are creating a Mac app.  I will edit the tags

Comment: I need them in company, not in AppStore.

Comment: @viktor.radovic Why should it be three different apps? Or two different apps, if the "third app" is an installer...? Can you describe your requirements a bit more in detail. Also do you have an enterprise developer account? That is needed if you want to distribute the app within your company and not app store. I can recommend distributing the apps using Crashlytics, which will create a short cut (looking like an app) on the users iPhone, where you can list the two apps. Like "your own app store"...

Comment: @Sajjon, this installer has to create two individual process, that should be active while the computer is turned on. User only starts installer one time, and afterwards those two processes are always active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of your project and problem is really vague.

It sounds like you should just scrap the three different targets and just use one target as a launcher for both process1.app and process2.app.  If your launcher has a GUI, create buttons that launch each process.  You can also modify your program to take command line arguments to launch process1, process2, or both from the command line.